# Архивация по Хаффману

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток!
Нашла в видео реализацию архивации по Хаффману, пробую, но компилятор ругается...Помогите разобраться

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
     int a;
     char c;
     Node *left, *right;

     Node(){left=right=NULL;}

     Node(Node *L, Node *R) 
     {  left =  L;
        right = R;
        a = L->a + R->a;  }
};

struct MyCompare
{
    bool operator()(const Node* l, const Node* r) const { return l->a < r->a; }
};

vector<bool> code;                
map<char,vector<bool> > table;

void BuildTable(Node *root)
{   
    if (root->left!=NULL) 
                      { code.push_back(0);
                      BuildTable(root->left);}

    if (root->right!=NULL)
                       { code.push_back(1);
                       BuildTable(root->right);}

    if (root->c) table[root->c]=code;

    code.pop_back();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
////// считаем частоты символов

    ifstream f("1.txt");

    map<char,int> m;

    while (!f.eof())
    { char c = f.get(); 
       m[c]++;}

////// записываем начальные узлы в список list

   list<Node*> t;
   for( map<char,int>::iterator itr=m.begin(); itr!=m.end(); ++itr)
   {  
      Node *p = new Node;
      p->c = itr->first;
      p->a = itr->second;  
      t.push_back(p);      }

//////  создаем дерево

  while (t.size()!=1)
  {  
     t.sort(MyCompare());

     Node *SonL = t.front();
     t.pop_front();
     Node *SonR = t.front(); 
     t.pop_front();

     Node *parent = new Node(SonL,SonR); 
     t.push_back(parent);

  }

    Node *root = t.front();   //root - указатель на вершину дерева

////// создаем пары 'символ-код':

    BuildTable(root);

////// Выводим коды в файл output.txt

    f.clear(); f.seekg(0); // перемещаем указатель снова в начало файла

    ofstream g("output.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

    int count=0; char buf=0;
    while (!f.eof())
    { char c = f.get();
      vector<bool> x = table[c];
      for(int n=0; n<x.size(); n++)
       {buf = buf | x[n]<<(7-count);   
        count++;   
        if (count==8) { count=0;   g<<buf; buf=0; } 
       }
    }

    f.close();
    g.close();

///// считывание из файла output.txt и преобразование обратно

    ifstream F("output.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian"); // чтоб русские символы отображались в командной строке

    Node *p = root;
    count=0; char byte; 
    byte = F.get();
    while(!F.eof())
    {   bool b = byte & (1 << (7-count) ) ; 
        if (b) p=p->right; else p=p->left;
        if (p->left==NULL && p->right==NULL) {cout<<p->c; p=root;}
        count++;
        if (count==8) {count=0; byte = F.get();}
    }

    F.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Пользуюсь MSVS2010
Ошибки:

> 1>------ Построение начато: проект: 1,
> Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------ 1>
> код.cpp 1>g:\documents and
> settings\gap\рабочий стол\код\новая
> папка\1\1\код.cpp(53): error C2079:
> "f" использует неопределенный class
> "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>"
> 1> with 1> [ 1> _Elem=char, 1>
> _Traits=std::char_traits<char> 1> ] 1>g:\documents and
> settings\gap\рабочий стол\код\новая
> папка\1\1\код.cpp(53): error C2440:
> инициализация: невозможно
> преобразовать "const char [6]" в "int"
> 1> Не существует контекста, в котором
> такое преобразование возможно
> 1>g:\documents and
> settings\amora\рабочий стол\код из
> часового видео\новая
> папка\1\1\код.cpp(57): error C2228:
> выражение слева от ".eof" должно
> представлять класс, структуру или
> объединение 1> тип: int 1>g:\documents
> and settings\gap\рабочий
> стол\код\новая папка\1\1\код.cpp(57):
> fatal error C1903: не удается
> восстановить после предыдущих ошибок;
> остановка компиляции
> ========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0,
> пропущено: 0 ==========

Comment: Попробуйте подключить в самом начале какой-нибудь `stdafx.h`, или что-то в этом роде. g++ этот код собирает без проблем, но не по Windows :)

Comment: Странно, вроде определения ifstream и basic_ifstream должны быть в <fstream>